# How to make PC work as Bluetooth headphones with Android devices?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio, media-button, audio-controls

I use my Android tablet/phone as a second screen and play media on it (YouTube videos, music, etc.) and send the audio to my PC where I listen to it through headphones. I use the application "Bluetooth audio receiver" from MS store.  The actual question - How do I use my PC to send a start/stop signal (AVRCP) to the android device.

Yes, of course you can tap on the screen for this, but I prefer tactile feedback from physical buttons. Besides, sometimes I still need to unlock the device first...

P.S. If necessary, I do not mind to change the application to transmit the sound itself.

Thanks in advance!